# Date formatting in Superset with MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

I have connected my MySQL DB to Superset and I can generate slices and dashboards. So far so good. Now when I add a Table View the dates are formatted as follows:

```
1500508800000
```

In the database they are stored as Date type as follows:

```
2014-06-23
```

In the slice editor I have set the Table Timestamp Format to:

```
%Y-%m-%d | 2019-01-14
```

The date is still not formatted. Is there something I need to do on the database side?

Comment: To keep tab, https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/3271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp appearing in the table is a known bug for version [0.18.5](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/3027). You can either downgrade or wait for the fixed version to be released.